# What went wrong?

Tags: software-installation

After downloading the 32-bit version I was not able to open the file. An error message displayed "application not found". What happened and what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to open the ISO file downloaded.  The error message that you're getting is because you don't have an application associated with ISO.  What you can do is either burn the ISO to DVD, or create a bootable USB flash drive.

If you're using windows, you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to create the DVD or use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable USB.

[image]

[image]

If running Ubuntu please see [Installing Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)